# Google Maps API - How to center marker and map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, geolocation

I have played around with the `geolocation` of `javascript`. So I created a `react` component, which shows your current location. I want to visualize this with Google Maps. It works fine so far, but however, if the current position moves outside the start map, the map does not pan. My goal is that the marker is always centered, and the map scrolls.
This is what I have so far. The current position is being passed to the component via the props `props.latitude` and `props.longitude`.

**UPDATE**

Now I know why this is not working.

`window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName("google-map"))`

is not working. It does not find the map this way. So it cannot update its properties. 
Anybody an idea how to access the current map?

Here is the code:

```
import React, {useState,useRef,useCallback} from 'react';
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose"
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps"

function Map(props) {
  const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: props.latitude, lng: props.longitude });
  const refMap = useRef(null);

  const handlePositionChanged = () => {
    let position = new window.google.maps.LatLng(parseInt(props.latitude), parseInt(props.longitude));
    window.google.maps.Marker(document.getElementsByClassName("google-map-marker")).setPosition(position);
    window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName("google-map")).setCenter(position);
  };

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      className="google-map"
      ref={refMap}
      defaultZoom={19}
      mapTypeId='satellite'
      defaultCenter={{ lat: props.latitude, lng: props.longitude }} 
      onBoundsChanged={useCallback(handlePositionChanged)}
    >
      <Marker className="google-map-marker" position={{ lat: props.latitude, lng: props.longitude }} position_changed={useCallback(handlePositionChanged)} />
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}

export default compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIz&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `500px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)((props) => <Map latitude={props.latitude} longitude={props.longitude} />);
```

Comment: Can you give it an ID instead of a className and access it by .getElementById ?

Comment: I tried this already. This does not work either...

Comment: Are you still having this issue @dns_nx ?

Comment: @evan Yes, still found no solution yet.

Comment: I see, could you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can fully reproduce this issue on our end?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the center of the map and the marker using `window.google.maps.`, you can use `state` values to change the `<GoogleMap/> center parameter` and the `<Marker/> position parameter`. So every time there's a change in the coordinates from geolocation, you need to change the state value of the Map's center and Marker's position and it the changes will then be reflected to the map. Here's a sample code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userPosition: { lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }
    };
  }

  onMapLoad = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
      this.setState({
        userPosition: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude }
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        center={this.state.userPosition}
        defaultZoom={13}
        onLoad={this.onMapLoad()}
      >
        <Marker position={this.state.userPosition} />
      </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: '500px' }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```